# Is there an iPod locator?

Tags: ipod-touch, utilities

I know the iPhone does that, using me.com, but I don't know anything similar for iPods. I have an iPod touch and, sometimes, I forget where I leave it, only knowing it's on my house.

If it was my cell, I would dial the number and listen. Is there a similar app for iPods?

Comment: what if you cant connect the me.com thing cuz i didnt install it before i lost it?

Comment: You should open that comment as a new question, Mandy.

Answer (score 2):

Your question and Webs' answer answer the question. With me.com, you can send an instant message to your iPod touch. Surely it needs WiFi turned on to receive the message. Additionally you can make the iPod beep for 120 seconds, and you can lock or reset it from remote.

Comment: How would the iPod receive those messages? Don't those apps use SMS to send information to the device?

Comment: It's an instant message that looks like and pops up like a system message. I tested it with my iPod Touch 8GB 2nd Gen, and it works.

Comment: That is pretty sweet! I wouldn't of expected them to accept the message over WiFi if it was an SMS message. But then again other jailbreak apps figured out SMS over WiFi too.

Comment: It's not SMS. It's Built off the Push Notifications system that Apple runs.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that most locating apps work using location services. Location services works by either triangulating the cell phone over cell connection or GPS. The iPod does not have a GPS or cell radio in it.

I have heard of location services using WiFi location, but then you would need location services installed and my guess is that it is not installed on the iPod. However, if it is, then you could connect to WiFi, turn on location, download an app to find your device, and then find it over WiFi. But accuracy is going to be hindered greatly using location over WiFi. Not to mention you would have to have the WiFi radio on to even find the device in this scenario. Which is impractical and not a good idea for good battery life.

Another option would be an app that when activated turns on the speaker of the iPod and beacons. But you would need a way to remotely turn this feature on. The only options here are Bluetooth and WiFi. Again the idea is hindered by needing one of those two radios always on. Which is impractical.

Probably the best options is one of those key finders. Key Ringer (http://www.keyringer.com/) is one such company. But the downside is you will need one of those bulky devices always attached to the iPod.

Comment: Wifi location works surprisingly well with the iPod touch, but I just want to find it in my house. Do you think is that impractical to have an app that connects somewhere to see if it needs to beep for some seconds? Maybe that's why I can't find it... But an app that turned the wifi on every 5 minutes just to check that status and then off again shouldn't be that inefficient. Maybe it could be considered a virus. Anyway, the devices are too bulky.

Comment: I agree on the bulkiness of devices, but due to the impracticality of the other solutions, it is probably the best. You are certainly free to leave your WiFi on for as long or as little as you like. But currently the only way to make one of those apps function correctly would be to have WiFi always on. No system exists yet to have WiFi just beacon on and off every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

MobileMe does this for iPod touches (if you have a paid account). You can also send a message and this will make a sound (if your iPod volume is high enough).